# RecyclerView: Is there a way to update the data withing without blocking the UI?

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a RecyclerView which has countdown timers in it. The countdown timers refresh once every second.

To refresh the timers, I simply call NotifyDataSetChanged every second. However doing so, means that the UI is blocked for a fraction of a second, every second. This leads to a choppy experience when scrolling and sometimes does not recognise user inputs.

So, is there a way to have the the update occur without blocking the UI?

Or, is there a way to only have the update occur when the user is not interacting with the view?

Or, am I going about it incorrectly? Should I try and access the view directly and somehow update the text in there, rather than updating the dataset?

Comment: Why are you keeping it refresh every second? Are you performing some network operation at the same time?